# H-bridge filtered Power Supply

Tags: power-supply

I have a question about H-bridge power supply: my motor works with 24DC. Do I have to use a switching power supply, or can I use a 24AC with a rectifier and capacitor?

Comment: do you need to control the motor's speed? do you need to reverse its direction of rotation?

Comment: 24V AC rectified produces much more than 24V DC.

Comment: Berto : yes i need to control the speed with a pwm and invert the sense of the rotation i think that's the hole meaning for using a H bridge right ? Richard crowely: thank you for your reponse

Answer (score 2):

If your only load is the motor via the H-bridge, then mains-frequency AC with a rectifier and capacitor is probably all you need. (At the proper voltage, of course.) And you don't need nearly as much filtering as you would with a more particular load (like logic or analog audio, etc.)

Comment: Just remember that 24Vac will rectify to ~34Vdc (peak), so you may have to PWM back a bit.

Comment: i did not forget that thanks for reminding me that :)